# Existence of an orthonormal basis of a conjugation operator $T$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Definition:

A map $T \colon H \to H$ ($H$ a Hilbert space) is called antilinear (or conjugate linear) if $$T(u +v) = Tu + Tv, \quad T(au) = a^* Tu,$$
where $a^*$ denotes the conjugation of $a$, for all $u, v \in H$ and scalars $a$.

An antilinear map $T$ is called an antiunitary operator if $R(T) = H$ and
$$(Tu, Tv) = (v, u) \qquad \text{for all } u, v \in H.$$
It is called a conjugation if, in addition, $T^2 = I$. Any antiunitary operator is the product of a conjugation and a unitary operator. These are just basic definitions, but I have no idea to show the following claim. The author just states it without any proof:

**Claim:** To any conjugation $T$ there corresponds an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, e_2, \ldots \}$ satisfying
$$T \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} a_i e_i = \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} a_i^* e_i$$
for all sequences $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ in
$$\ell^2(\mathbb N) = \bigg\{(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} : \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} \lvert a_i \rvert^2 < \infty \bigg\}. $$

Comment: Welcome to this community. It is mendatory to use MathJax (see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question more accesible.

Comment: What spectral theorem(s) do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
K_+=\{x:\ Tx=x\}=\{x+Tx: x\},
$$
and $$K_-=\{x:\ Tx=-x \}=\{x -Tx:\ x\}.$$
These are real subspaces, with $H=K_++K_-$ and $K_+\cap K_-=\{0\}$. If $x\in K_+$, then $T(ix)=-ix $. It follows that $K_-=iK_+$; this guarantees that $K_+\ne\{0\}$.

Given nonzero $e_1\in K_+$ and $y\perp e_1$, we have $$\langle Ty,e_1\rangle=\langle Te_1,y\rangle=\langle e_1,y\rangle=0.$$ So $\{e_1\}^\perp$ is invariant for $T$ and we can decompose $\{e_1\}^\perp$ as $K_+'+K_-'$ as before. So there exists a nonzero $e_2$ with $Te_2=e_2$ and $e_2\perp e_1$. Let $\{e_j\}$ be a maximal orthonormal family in $K_+$. If $\{e_j\}^\perp\ne\{0\}$, then using the above argument we can enlarge the family, a contradiction. Hence $\{e_j\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$ with $Te_j=e_j$ for all $j$, and the claim is satisfied: since  $T$ is bounded (being an isometry),
$$
T\Big(\sum_ja_je_j\Big)=\sum_jT(a_je_j)=\sum_j\bar a_j\, e_j.
$$